# field not empty on call dopost

Tags: java, servlets

When calling servlet, some fields are not empty at the calling of dopost. 
How to be sure that the field is always null while starting the servlet.
Example:

```
import java.io.*;    
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;   
import java.util.Map;   
public class gererEmployeur extends HttpServlet{
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
  Personne p=null;
  @Override
  public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
throws ServletException,IOException{
   System.out.print(p);
   //p is not null
  }
}
```

Comment: It this the whole code? Do you set p to something else than `null` somewhere else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use instance fields. The container only creates one Servlet instance to handle all requests. That instance variable is shared between all your requests. Don't do that. Simply use a local variable.

Comment: Is there any way to create one instance of the servlet at every call ?

Comment: @user No, this is part of the specification.

Comment: Please I would like to know how and where to make specification so that at any call a new instance of servlet is created

Comment: @user3622677 No, I mean the Servlet Specification mandates that only one Servlet is created. You cannot change this. Change your application design instead.